# Using TeX in matplotlib with Spyder opens multiple cmd windows on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

I am using Python 3.6 with Spyder 3.1.4 on a Windows 10 machine. My code generates a number of plots and, to include these in a TeX document I'm writing, I'd like to use TeX for all fonts in the plots. This was when I found this quite annoying situation.

Using the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Times']})
rc('text', usetex=True)

A = range(5)
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(A, B, '--', label= "a dashed line")
plt.legend()
```

I get multiple cmd.exe windows popping up and closing when I run it. If I try to pan the axis around inside the figure I also get these cmd.exe windows opening and closing very quickly. It gets to the point where it is quite impossible to work with the plots with the amount of cmd.exe windows that open up - they don't stop showing up for a long time even after the code finished running and the figures are generated.

Any help or indication on what could be wrong? I am completely lost here on how to solve this annoyance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Have you performed all steps at [matplotlib tex troubleshooting](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#troubleshooting)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have tried everything there. Deleted the tex cache, added my MikTeX directory to PATH, installed Ghostscript 9.2 for Windows on my Anaconda 3 directory, which is also on PATH. My Anaconda distribution did not have the [ghostscript package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ghostscript), so I downloaded the .tar.bz2 and left it on the pkgs folder on my Anaconda installation. Any other suggestions? I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: Since I have never seen this issue, I cannot help more, I guess. Note, that there is also a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8487) about this without any conclusion.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest well thank you anyway. I guess I'm off to using Matplotlib's font without TeX. Any idea on how to change that font to match TeX's? That sure would be a messy workaround, but I suppose it wouldn't be perceptible on the document.

Comment: I think there are a lot of questions about latex fonts. If you don't find what you're looking for ask a new question to keep this one clean, as this is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same exact problem, and it sure is annoying! :) Also using windows 10. However, I was able to get the latex fonts to work correctly - it strongly depended on the wording and location of the statement *rc('text', usetex=True)*

In your comments above you say you've installed a LaTeX distribution and GS - so I think the issue may be with what you've written. For example instead try this, it worked for me:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import rc

mpl.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
A = range(5)
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(A, B, '--', label= "a dashed line")
plt.xlabel(r"$\lambda$",fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel(r"$\Phi$",fontsize=12)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Note: I am using the IDLE environment.

The image below shows that an error code may pop up after your script terminates, but it seems to be harmless (and I did not spend much time trying to troubleshoot it!).

[image]

Play around with it a bit to see what works and doesn't work, but I hope this helps!